# Parallelizing Sparsematrix with OpenMP

Tags: c, matrix, count, openmp, sparse-matrix

I have a problem with storing the values in my array. I know the problem comes from my counter which does not count as it is supposed to in OpenMP. I wonder if someone has any tips on how to store my values in my created arrays. My function is written in c. Also I am aware of the fact that this multiplication can have multiple values for the same Newi_element and Newj_element which have to be added to each other.

```
#define N 1138 //Matrix size

void matrixmultiplication(void){
int *Newi_element = malloc(sizeof(int)*N *N);
int *Newj_element = malloc(sizeof(int)*N *N);
float *Newvalues = malloc(sizeof(float)*N *N);
int Newniterate = 0;
int i,j;    
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel 
{
#pragma omp for private(i,j)
for(i=0;i<niterate;i++){
    for(j=0;j<niterate2;j++){
        if((j_element[i] == i_element2[j])){
                *(Newi_element+Newniterate) = i_element[i];
                *(Newj_element+Newniterate) = j_element2[j];
                *(Newvalues+Newniterate) = values[i] * values2[j];
                Newniterate++;
        }
    }
}
}
free(Newi_element);
free(Newj_element);
free(Newvalues);
```

}

Comment: hi @Nathan can you post more information explaining what you are trying to do with the code.
What are `i_element[]` and `j_element[]`.... ?
how data is stored in `values[]` and `values[2]`?

Comment: You should create for each thread a local buffer of limited size where the `Newi`, `Newj` and `Newvalues` are stored. When the buffer is full or the loop is complete, the local buffer can be offloaded to the global `Newi` , etc from within an `omp critical` section. Hopefully, the (serialized) offloading time will be short with respect to parallel computation time. The subject is very similar to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038117/cache-management-for-sparse-matrix-multiplication-using-openmp)